# VSTest Execute each dll individually

Tags: c#, mstest, azure-devops, vstest

I'd like to create a VSTS build definition where I can specify vstest.console.exe to execute on any dll that contains the word *test*. This definition would be:

```
**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

This executes a command like the following for my repository:

```
2016-04-08T20:38:41.4966824Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe 
"E:\A\_work\33\s\A\UnitTests\bin\Release\A.UnitTests.dll" 
"E:\A\_work\33\s\A\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll" 
"E:\A\_work\33\s\B\UnitTests\bin\Release\B.UnitTests.dll" 
"E:\A\_work\33\s\B\UnitTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll" 
/logger:trx
```

The issue I'm having is that the dll's A & B have dependencies on the same dll names but different versions, this means vstest.console.exe can't simultaneously load the dll and one of the two cases is bound to fail.

Is there a way to force vstest.console.exe to load seperately for each dll? I tried /InInsolation but it did not resolve the issue

I know that executing each dll separately via a different vstest.console.exe command would work, but that's cumbersome to achieve in VSTS. Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with "Run In Parallel" feature. Check the "Run In Parallel" option in "Visual Studio Test" step or enable it by using a testsetting file.

> Parallel Test Execution
>
> The Visual Studio Test Platform introduces support parallel execution
>   of test cases.
>
> Parallel test execution leverages the available cores on the machine,
>   and is realized by launching the test execution engine on each
>   available core as a distinct process, and handing it a container
>   (assembly, DLL, or relevant artifact containing the tests to execute),
>   worth of tests to execute. The unit of scheduling is the test
>   container. Within each container, the tests will be executed as per
>   the semantics of the test framework. If there are many such
>   containers, then as processes finish executing the tests within a
>   container, they are handed the next available container.

Refer to this link for details: [Parallel Test Execution](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs#misc)

However, in my mind, the simplest way to do this is adding an additional "Visual Studio Test" step in your build definition. Then you can configure one VSTest task to execute A.UnitTests.dll and another VSTest task to execute B.UnitTests.dll.